# JobScheduler won't restart when condition meets the requirements

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler

I have set my `JobScheduler` to start when phone is charging and connected to wifi. But when I turn off wifi it says job cancelled, but when I turn it back on it won't restart. Here's my code:
MainActivity.java

```
private static final String TAG="MainActivity";
public void scheduleJob(View v) {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, ExampleJobService.class);
    JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
            .build();

    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
    if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
    }
}

public void cancelJob(View v){
    JobScheduler scheduler=(JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    scheduler.cancel(123);
    Log.d(TAG,"Job cancelled");
}
```

ExampleJobService.java

```
private static final String TAG="ExampleJobService";
private boolean jobCanceled=false;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job started");
    doBackgroundWork(params);

    return true;
}

private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "run: " + i);
                if (jobCanceled) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Job finished");
            jobFinished(params, false);
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before completion");
    jobCanceled = true;
    return true;
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hoversfw.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ExampleJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I turn off wifi, schedule job, kill app process, and turn wifi on, the JobScheduler starts and I see it printing in the Logcat. Also, when I schedule it and it starts, then kill app, it just stopped printing in Logcat. So I think whenever the JobScheduler got interrupted, it just won't restart. I have permissions added, and minSDK is 21. So there should be no problem about permissions. Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JobSchleduler will be restart when you call `jobFinished(params, true)`. You can add it before return

```
if (jobCanceled) {
    jobFinished(params, true);
    return;
}
```

Comment: It works, but I see it's taking almost one minute to start the process. Is that normal?

Comment: Sure normal, as i know if retry many time the timeout will be increasing